# How would I fix this multi-table query to select only the rows that are needed?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a query that selects all messages from a specific user and all of that user's friends. This query almost works, but the first part causes issues because it ends up selecting all rows from 'friends.' I'm thinking I need to use some sort of JOIN for this to work as needed, but I don't have enough experience with JOINS to make this work after experimenting for over an hour now.

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM messages a, friends b 
 WHERE a.username = '$user' OR b.username = '$user' && b.friend = a.username 
 ORDER BY a.id DESC 
 LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM messages a
 WHERE a.username = '$user' 
    OR a.username in (SELECT b.friend FROM friends b WHERE b.username = '$user') 
 ORDER BY a.id DESC 
 LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Perfect, totally forgot you could put a query inside IN().

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
   SELECT m.*
     FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN friends f
       ON m.username = f.username
    WHERE m.username = "$user"
       OR f.friend = "$user"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work since there isn't guaranteed to be an entry in 'friends,' but they still could have messages.

Comment: I've changed query a bit in my answer, does it work better this way?